# Why did jetty server not agree to a protocol while sending a request?

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, jetty, apache-karaf

**Java version**

1.8

**Jetty version**

9.3.x

> - Trying :13443...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Connected to  (10.61.45.225) port 13443 (#0)
> - ALPN, offering http/1.1
> - Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
> - TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
>     ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
>     Server certificate:
>     subject: CN=karaf@
>     start date: Jan 23 07:06:56 2020 GMT
>     expire date: Jul 23 07:07:06 2020 GMT
>     issuer: CN=
>     SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
>     GET /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1
>     Host: :13443
>     User-Agent: curl/7.65.0
>     Accept: */*
>     Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
>     < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>     < Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2020 10:53:03 GMT
>     < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>     < Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8;profile=some-value#
>     < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>     < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>     < Content-Length: 305
>     < Server: Jetty(9.3.21.v20170918)
>     <

My question is which protocol is being disagreed to by the server ? As per the logs, it seems the ALPN offered to use http/1.1 and the server might have disagreed to it and hence the log.

Is there any solution to this ?

**Why a solution is required ?**

I am thinking that because of this the request which was originally sent as a https request resolved to a http request when debugged in the code. See the logs below.
[image]

Comment: As per the logs, the handshake is happening over TLSv1.2 from both the sides. Isn't that right ? If it is, doesn't that mean server is talking over the same protocol as well ?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Here is my java version 1.8.0_231

Comment: OK ... so you probably need to read / go through this: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html.  You need to do ... things ... to get ALPN to work with Java 8 and Jetty.

Comment: I did read it but couldn't make much sense out of it. Is there a better place to read about it ? Or maybe Ill try reading it again.

Comment: I think you should try to read it again.  It says that you need to do some specific things on the server side if you are using Java 8.  If you haven't done anything, my guess is that it won't work.

Comment: The document mentions that this change is needed for java based on openJDK8, mine is not based on openJDK.

Comment: Oracle Java >>is<< based on OpenJDK.  OpenJDK is the codebase for by Oracle and OpenJDK distros.  The alternative would be (for example) IBM Java or Oracle's Rockit Java.   Or Java 9.

Comment: Here are my jetty server logs (I opened a ticket on jetty's source code). https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/4516#issuecomment-578616596 . Do take a look at at it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that jetty didn't have ssl configured properly. To solve that I added the following configration to it.

```
<New id="tlsHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration"> <Arg> <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration"> <!-- This says... Redirect to https://host:8443 if server returns "NOT SECURE" error --> <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set> <Set name="securePort">8443</Set> </New> </Arg> <Call name="addCustomizer"> <Arg> <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer" /> </Arg> </Call> </New>
```